# Convergence problem in pspice but not in ltspice

Tags: simulation, spice, ltspice

I am trying to simulate a circuit in LTSPICE and it simulates without any convergence problems. However when I copy the netlist into pspice and try it simulate it I get strange results. It keeps saying convergence problems in pspice. However in LTSPICE it simulates the circuit correctly. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Common enough problem I imagine but it is circuit dependent so show the circuit

Comment: You need to post your schematic to get an answer to this.

Comment: about 20 years ago I managed a team of EE's designing an analog IC. The single biggest problem keeping on schedule was convergence in SPICE! we were using PSPICE at the time, have heard of the same issue with HSPICE as well.

Comment: since the tools use numerical computation techniques, the starting state is incredibly critical to success of the algorithm. SPICE takes the present state, and applies an incremental time and calculates the "next state", and iterates until it settles at all nodes. then increment and do it again. But you have to start somewhere and thats where convergence for initial state comes in.

Comment: we ended up putting some dummy parts in, like meg-ohm resistors, and voltage sources, to force nodes to be at a different starting state, and that helped. but its trial and error, which makes schedules slip!

Comment: Sometimes changing the integration method can help convergence.  Trapezoidal works best for circuits with oscillators, Gear works best sometimes for switchmode power circuits.